# Ubuntu 21.10 hangs on shutdown/poweroff/reboot

Tags: boot, drivers, ssd, shutdown, hardware

I have research solutions for days now and I can't find the correct solutions e.g GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT "acpi=force" "nomodeset" but nothing is working. I also updated my additional drivers for my video card
Here are some details
[image]

Here is my system about
[image]

also here is my additional drivers
[image]

also here are my disk. I have 1 ssd and 1hdd. Not sure if they are connected to the issue. I have the OS installed on the ssd.
[image]

Let me know if there is something I can do. Thank you so much. New Ubuntu user here

Comment: You may need some change in UEFI settings and/or update it as well.